# Is there a way to get programmatically UI hierarchy for 3rd party application on iOS?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, iphone-privateapi

I am looking for a way to get programmatically UI hierarchy of 3rd party application.

Couple of constrains:

- I am looking for a way to get UI of 3rd party app (**so I can't include any library in it or change a code**)
- It should work on a real iOS device (not on Simulator)
- It should work with non jailbroken device.
- It should work with native app

I am fine with either:

- A desktop tool which can access iOS and get info about an app hierarchy
- An iOS app which can get UI hierarchy for 3rd party app while being in the background
- I am fine with usage of private API (it won't be submitted to AppStore)

Any ideas (even if they aren't complete solution) are welcome.

Comment: Has anybody ported X11 to an app?

Comment: @QED: How is it related to a question?

Answer (score 1):

SparkInspector http://www.sparkinspector.com is similar to Reveal, but I'm not sure is it able to work with real device.

Comment: This requires application modification. You have to add their framework into your project. So, it won't work with 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend DCIntrospect: https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect

Also there is Reveal: http://revealapp.com

Comment: Both DCIntrospect and Reveal require adding a library to your application. So, it won't work with 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the Reveal dynamic library into a third-party application using MobileSubstrate. This can only be performed though via a jailbroken device. Blog post describing the process:
http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?p=2361

Comment: One of constrains which I wrote in my question was "It should work with non jailbroken device."

Comment: Yes, yes you did. Sorry I got side-tracked by the other answers here, and didn't read all of your dot-points. But looking at your dotpoints, you won't be able to achieve this without jailbreaking / injecting custom code. Imagine if I could remotely inspect the 'UI' of someone's banking application, the standard security model prevents this regardless of private APIs

Comment: Probably you are right. However, I was hopping that may be some desktop utility exist which can do this (taking into account that device anyway needs to trust to the desktop before any other operation will be done).

Comment: And one more thing. iOS has some private APIs which are definitely not compatible with their own security model. So, there is a chance that such API which allow to read 3rd party hierarchy exist.